# Add third element in list of tuple having three elements each , if first two elements are Identical

Tags: python, list, tuples

How can I add third element to the tuple, if first two elements are same?.
Here in list we have three tuples having first two identical elements `6220` and `586` . 
So that we need to create a new single tuple like this `[(6220,586,(5+5+5))]`.

```
list = [(6220, 586, 5), (7032, 621, 0), (7030, 589, 0), (7032, 621, 0), (6220, 586, 5), (7030, 589, 0), (7032, 621, 0), (6220, 586, 5)]
```

Expected Output :

`[(6220, 586, 15),(7032, 621, 0),(7030, 589, 0)]`

so far i have come up with the following :

```
a_b=[]
for x in lst:
    for y in lst:
        if len(a_b) == 0:
            a_b.append((x[0],x[1],x[2]))
        if x[0]==y[0] and x[1]==y[1]:
                if (x[0],x[1],x[2]+y[2]) not in a_b:
                    t=(x[0],x[1],x[2]+y[2])
                    a_b.append(t)
```

Comment: This returns an array of arrays, but does the job: `import pandas as pd;
groupped = pd.DataFrame(list).groupby([0,1]).sum().reset_index().values`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If order matters, I'd make an OrderedCounter to sum on pairs, then combine pair keys with value:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict, Counter
>>> l1= [(6220, 586, 5), (7032, 621, 0), (7030, 589, 0), (7032, 621, 0), (6220, 586, 5), (7030, 589, 0), (7032, 621, 0), (6220, 586, 5)]
>>> class OrderedCounter(Counter, OrderedDict):
...     pass
...
>>> oc = OrderedCounter()
>>> for a,b,c in l1:
...     oc[a,b] += c
...
>>> oc
OrderedCounter([((6220, 586), 15), ((7032, 621), 0), ((7030, 589), 0)])
```

Finally:

```
>>> result = [k+(v,) for k,v in oc.items()]
>>> result
[(6220, 586, 15), (7032, 621, 0), (7030, 589, 0)]
>>>
```

If order doesn't matter, then a plain `Counter` would suffice.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a simple aggregation of integers (`defaultdict` can shorten things up):

```
from collections import defaultdict                        
agg = defaultdict(int)                                     
for item in lst:                                           
    agg[item[:2]] += item[2]   

result = [(k[0], k[1], v,) for k, v in agg.iteritems()]
```

Result:

```
[(6220, 586, 15), (7032, 621, 0), (7030, 589, 0)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(int)
list_ = [(6220, 586, 5), (7032, 621, 0), (7030, 589, 0), (7032, 621, 0), (6220, 586, 5), (7030, 589, 0), (7032, 621, 0), (6220, 586, 5)]

for l in list_:
    d[l[0:2]] += l[-1]
#defaultdict(int, {(6220, 586): 15, (7030, 589): 0, (7032, 621): 0})
[tuple(list(k) + [v]) for k, v in d.items()]
```

out:

```
    [(6220, 586, 15), (7032, 621, 0), (7030, 589, 0)]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a functional programming classic! Here it is:

```
from itertools import groupby
from functools import reduce

lst = [(6220, 586, 5), (7032, 621, 0), (7030, 589, 0), (7032, 621, 0), (6220, 586, 5), (7030, 589, 0), (7032, 621, 0), (6220, 586, 5)]

ab = []
for k, v in groupby(sorted(lst), lambda t: (t[0], t[1])):
    ab.append(reduce(lambda x, y: (x[0], x[1], x[2] + y[2]), v))

print(ab)

>>>
[(6220, 586, 15), (7030, 589, 0), (7032, 621, 0)]
```